# String no print c++

Tags: c++

i'm very new in programming, i have this big code, but when i try to print the data never prints the string variable, can you help?
this is just for
i use "goto" just for practicall reassons.

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;

    class producto
    {
    public:
        int id;
        string nombre;
        string descripcion;
        int precio;
        void registrar();
        void ver();
    };
    void producto::registrar()
    {
        cout << "Codigo:" << endl;
        cin >> id;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Nombre del producto:" << endl;
        getline(cin, nombre);
        cout << "Descripcion del producto:" << endl;
        getline(cin, descripcion);
        cout << "Precio:" << endl;
        cin >> precio;

    }
    void producto::ver()
    {
        cout << "ID del producto:";
        cout << id << endl;
        cout << "Nombre del producto:" << endl;
        cout << nombre;
        cout << "Descripcion del producto:";
        cout << descripcion<<endl;
        cout << "Precio:";
        cout << "$" << precio << endl;

    }
int main()
{
menu1:
    int menu;
    producto cosa;
    cout << "************************" << endl;
    cout << "1.- Registrar Producto" << endl;
    cout << "2.- Ver Producto" << endl;
    cout << "************************" << endl;
    cin >> menu;
    cin.ignore();
    switch (menu)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "INGRESE PRODUCTO NUEVO:\nPresione enter para continuar" << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        system("cls");
        cosa.registrar();
        cin.ignore();
        break;
    case 2:
        cosa.ver();
        cout << "Presione enter para regresar al menu principal." << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        break;

    }
    goto menu1;
    return 0;
}
```

Edit
Here is the int main

Comment: What's your `main` function?

Comment: Could you add a `main()` where you use your class ?

Comment: Move the `producto cosa;` above the `menu1:`, as currently it creates a new `producto` each time round the loop, losing your previously-entered data.

Comment: Oh, thanks A LOT, you've solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `goto` is not recommended and considered a very bad practice even for a beginner. If you are begining in C++, following best practice is the best way to begin. The `goto` is supported in C/C++ only for backward compatibility.

For your issue try to use a loop instead of a `goto`.

```
int main()
{   
    //Condition to show the menu or exit
    bool bContinue = true;
    producto cosa;

    do{

        int menu;
        cout << "************************" << endl;
        cout << "1.- Registrar Producto" << endl;
        cout << "2.- Ver Producto" << endl;
        cout << "3.- Exit" << endl;
        cout << "************************" << endl;
        cin >> menu;
        cin.ignore();

        switch (menu)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "INGRESE PRODUCTO NUEVO:\nPresione enter para continuar" << endl;
            cin.ignore();
            system("cls");
            cosa.registrar();
            cin.ignore();
            break;
        case 2:
            cosa.ver();
            cout << "Presione enter para regresar al menu principal." << endl;
            cin.ignore();
            break;
        case 3:
            bContinue = false;
            break;
        }

    }while(bContinue)
    return 0;
}
```

Like this way, your issue will be fixed and you learn a better way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't a loop because it's suppose we can't use them yet.